# Testing samba performance with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualhost, samba

I have set up a VM in Virtualbox to test the effects of samba configuration changes in terms of read/write transfer speed. But successive read transfer speeds have sometimes more than 10 Mbps differences and for write speeds there are sometimes more than 5 Mbps differences.

My test: write and read 100 Mb to the samba share to get the speeds.

- Samba version: 3.6.23
- VM OS: CentOS 6.6
- Host OS: Windows 7

Working with a VM and with a network based on VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter, would it be too much to expect same speeds if nothing changes or not more than 1-2 Mbps differences?

I have got the warning that physical hosts, adapters, different configurations, environments, etc. can signifcantly modify the results but still I want to be able to test samba speeds in a comfortable manner.

Comment: Why are you using VirtualBox on Windows, then?

Comment: Because the target hosts for SAMBA are Windows clients, so I test it from my Windows host. You suggest that running the VM from Windows causes the samba to behave unpredictably?